# jQuery function running before being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call, gsap

I have two functions that I want to be called one after the other. The first function runs fine but the 2nd one runs even before it's called. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? The first function is called scrollAnimation() and the 2nd probmatic one is called footerAnimation. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mainGraphic').css('visibility','hidden');

        (new TimelineLite({onComplete:scrollAnimation}))
                .from( $('#header'), 1, {css:{opacity:'0'}})
                .from( $('#fade-headerText'), .7, {css:{bottom:'1000px', opacity:'0'}, ease:Back.easeOut})
                .from( $('#boxQ'), .7, {delay: 1, css:{opacity:'0'}})
                .from( $('#boxS'), .7, {css:{opacity:'0'}})
                .from( $('#boxSim'), .7, {css:{opacity:'0'}})

                function scrollAnimation() {
                    $('#mainGraphic').css('visibility','visible');

                    var controller = $.superscrollorama();


                    controller.addTween('#graphicOne', TweenMax.from( $('#graphicOne'), 1, {css:{right:'1000px', opacity:'0'}, ease:Back.easeOut}));
                    controller.addTween('#graphicTwo', TweenMax.from( $('#graphicTwo'), 1, {css:{left:'1000px', opacity:'0'}, ease:Back.easeOut})); 
                    controller.addTween('#graphicThree', TweenMax.from( $('#graphicThree'), 1, {css:{right:'1000px', opacity:'0'}, ease:Back.easeOut}));

                    footerAnimation();  

                }

                function footerAnimation() {
                    TweenMax.to( $('#footerTextLight'), .7, {delay: 2, css:{opacity:'1'}})
                    TweenMax.to( $('#footerTextDark'), .7, {delay:2, css:{opacity:'1'}})
                }
    });
```

Comment: It's not running "before it's being called".  The animation calls start asynchronous activity, so the call to "footerAnimation()" happens before the animation is finished.

Comment: Is there a way to delay this until the animation completes

Comment: The documentation to that scroller software says that there's a way to pass a function as an "onComplete" property, but I can't tell exactly how it's supposed to work. I'm not familiar with that code.

Comment: Woops didn't know you could use that indivually thanks!